# Banner image being cropped

Tags: css, image, wordpress

I'm trying to add images to a banner that was included with the WordPress template I'm using, but it's cropping the images instead of scaling them properly.
I noticed that the height of the banner was too small, but I can't seem to be able to change it in the CSS code.
This is the page where I'm trying to sort out the banner - [Money Matters Home](http://bojomedia.co.uk/preview/moneymatters/), and this is the original image that I uploaded - [home-banner-1.png](http://bojomedia.co.uk/img/home-banner-1.png)

As you can see, it's being cropped from the original, despite the fact that I've tried to change the height of the banner. The original image dimensions are 900 x 278, and it should scale naturally to 1152 x 355, but isn't.

Does anyone know how to sort this out? I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here!

Comment: The cropping size would most likely be defined in some php code. CSS will just tell it how to display the image, not how to upload/customize/etc

Comment: Maybe you selected the medium size of image im WP when you uploaded it. Try checking the actual size of image when you upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change dimensions of your image first to `870x230` (as i see the dimensions of current banner) - you can do it in Photoshop or even Paint.

Then when you upload image in Wordpress via Uploader, Upload the Image file and Select "Original" option in Size of image before saving rather than small/medium/large etc

Your current image banner file is: `http://bojomedia.co.uk/preview/moneymatters/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/home-banner-1-temp-870x230.png`

note `870x230` at the end of that file name - This is wordpress generated cropped version of original file that's being used there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Although I was adding images via the Featured Image section (can't choose the size), I did use your suggestiosn, plus I found some code in the theme's functions.php that was cropping the image.

Answer (score 2):

You could just re-size the image in Photoshop or Gimp to the exact dimensions of the WordPress header.

Use your browsers developer inspect tool to figure out the exact dimensions.